# How do I access an attribute value based on a different attribute value?

Tags: ruby, xpath, attributes, nokogiri

I'm in the process of teaching myself Ruby and Nokogiri. I have an nmap scan, output as below:

```
<host starttime="1368204336" endtime="1368204506"><status state="up" reason="arp-  response" reason_ttl="0"/>
<address addr="192.168.1.254" addrtype="ipv4"/>
<address addr="88:53:D4:07:F1:3B" addrtype="mac" vendor="Huawei Technologies Co."/>
```

I'm trying to use Nokogiri to extract just the IP address by stating it should ignore `if addrtype="mac"`. Here's my code:

```
hosts = nmap_file.xpath('//host/address/@addr') if nmap_file.xpath('//host/address[not(@addrtype="mac")]')
```

This doesn't work, and when I `puts hosts` the MAC addresses are still included. Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an `if` statement; you can do this in a single XPath statement.

```
.xpath('//host/address[not(@addrtype="mac")]/@addr')
```

You just select the `address` elements you want, then grab the `addr` attribute. You were close.